# Android. Navigation Architecture Component. Проблема с функцией popBackStack

Tags: android, kotlin

В своем приложении я использую Navigation Architecture Component и архитектуру MVVM (так как понимаю ее, возможны какие-то ошибки).

У меня есть главная Activity, а экраны приложения - это фрагменты. нас интересуют два из них (пусть будут Fragment1 и Fragment2).
Часть Fragment1:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState) 

    sendCodeButton.setOnClickListener {
        viewModel.requestResetCode()
    }

    viewModel.codeRequestSuccess.observe(this, object  : Observer<Boolean> {
        override fun onChanged(t: Boolean?) {
            if (t != null && t == true) {
                view?.findNavController()?.navigate(R.id.action_forgotPasswordFragment_to_resetCodeFragment)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

То есть на первом фрагменте (Fragment1) у меня осуществляется переход на второй фрагмент (Fragment2), но происходит это не сразу по нажатию, а как только viewModel проверит правильность данных. Для этого Fragment1 отслеживает переменную **codeRequestSuccess**, которая является **MutableLiveData**.

Вот так выглядит код в ViewModel который отвечает за проверку данных:

```
fun requestResetCode() {
    subscription = loginApi.requestResetCode(login.value!!)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnSubscribe { onCodeRequestStart() }
                .doOnTerminate { onCodeRequestFinish() }
                .subscribe(
                        { result -> onResetCodeReceived(result) },
                        { onCodeRequestError() }
                )
}

private fun onResetCodeReceived(result: Boolean) {
    codeRequestSuccess.value = result      
}
```

Переход осуществляется нормально, на нужный фрагмент. Но когда я потом в Fragment2 пытаюсь вернуться обратно на Fragment1:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    backArrow.setOnClickListener {
        view.findNavController().popBackStack()
    }
}
```

Ничего не происходит, нажатие срабатывает, но перехода нет. Я проверил количество фрагментов в стэке - 0. При этом если в Fragment1 сделать простой переход (для проверки) на Fragment2:

```
sendCodeButton.setOnClickListener {
       view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_forgotPasswordFragment_to_resetCodeFragment)          
    }
```

Я понимаю, что, скорее всего дело в том как или откуда делается переход. Может не тот поток или процесс используется, может еще что-то связанное с этим. Но что именно не так, понять не могу.

Comment: Всю логику работы с фрагментами я советую перенести в Activity. После этого создать у каждого фрагмента свой интерфейс для взаимодействия с Activity. (а в Activity его заимплементить) , переопределить метод onBackPressed() под нужное поведение или добавлять фрагменты во FragmentManager c addToBackStack(@param name -  An optional name for this back stack state, or null.)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Попробовал вынести всю навигацию в активити, это не помогло.

Answer (score 0):

После долгих экспериментов, я нашел решение, но пока все равно не понял до конца причины ошибки. Скорее всего она связанна с тем как Kotlin работает со статическими классами, объектами и полями (их в чистом виде, по моему, нет). Так или иначе, я просто заменил объявление обработчика изменений переменной **MutableLiveData**. Вместо :

```
viewModel.codeRequestSuccess.observe(this, object  : Observer<Boolean> {
    override fun onChanged(t: Boolean?) {
        if (t != null && t == true) {
            view?.findNavController()?.navigate(R.id.action_forgotPasswordFragment_to_resetCodeFragment)
        }
    }
})
```

Я оформил обработчик в отдельное свойство класса :

```
private val listener:Observer<Boolean> = object : Observer<Boolean> {
    override fun onChanged(t: Boolean?) {
        if (t != null && t == true) {
            view?.findNavController()?.navigate(R.id.action_forgotPasswordFragment_to_resetCodeFragment)
        }
    }
}
....
 viewModel.codeRequestSuccess.observe(this, listener)
```

Так все заработало.